# How to reload TileOverlay for geoserver tiles on android google map v2 implementation

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geoserver

I am using a geoserve implementation for retrieving my maps tiles. 
The way I request the tiles is when camera change view on the maps it trigger my api call sending the lat and lng of the centre view of map afterwards the api resposne the list of geoserver layers need for TileOverlay's getTileUrl.

But unfortunately by the time my Api return the list of layers getTileUrl is already fired and my tile are not rendered.

In short the layers parameter for my geoserver request is dynamically changing.. so my question is how do I trigger to load again the map overlay so that when my Api returns the list it reload the overlay with the proper layers.

Here is my implementation of OnCameraChangeListener:

```
private GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener cameraChange = new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        LatLng latLng = map.getCameraPosition().target;
        getLayerLists(latLng);
    }
};
```

Here is getLayerList method:

```
private void getLayerList(LatLng latLng) {
    nigsApi.getLayerForArea(TAG_FLOOD_MAP_REQUEST,
            String.valueOf(latLng.latitude), String.valueOf(latLng.longitude),
            onApiResponse);
}
```

Here is the onApiResponse callback returning the layer list:

```
private OnApiResponse<NigsApi.ResponsePair<List<String>>> onApiResponse = new OnApiResponse<NigsApi.ResponsePair<List<String>>>() {
    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccessful(NigsApi.ResponsePair<List<String>> result) {
        tileProviderFactory.setLayerArea(result.getResult());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailed(String errorMessage, Object tag) {
        Log.e("Maps", errorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestError(RetrofitError error, Object tag) {
        Log.e("Maps", error.getMessage());
    }
};
```

After the response it goes to My TileProviderFactory class and set the list of layers needed for getTileUrl.

Here is the block for getTileUrl:

```
public void setLayerArea(List<String> listLayer){
    this.listLayer = listLayer;
}    

public WmsTileProvider getOsgeoWmsTileProvider() {

    //This is configured for:
    // http://beta.sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/maps/services
    // (TODO check that this WMS service still exists at the time you try to run this demo,
    // if it doesn't, find another one that supports EPSG:900913
    final String WMS_FORMAT_STRING =
            "http://202.90.153.87:8080/geoserver/flood_100/wms?" +
                    "service=WMS" +
                    "&version=1.1.0" +
                    "&request=GetMap" +
                    "&bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f" +
                    "&width=256" +
                    "&height=256" +
                    "&srs=EPSG:900913" +
                    "&format=image/png" +
                    "&transparent=true" +
                    "&tiled=true";

    WmsTileProvider tileProvider = new WmsTileProvider(256,256) {
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            double[] bbox = getBoundingBox(x, y, zoom);

            String layerTitles = getLayerTitles();

            String s = String.format(Locale.US, WMS_FORMAT_STRING, bbox[MINX],
                    bbox[MINY], bbox[MAXX], bbox[MAXY]);

            s = s + layerTitles;

            Log.e("MapLayers", s);
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(s);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
            return url;
        }
    };

    return tileProvider;
}
```

The method getLayerTitles() concat all layers into one string and append it to WMS_FORMAT_STRING url..

```
private String getLayerTitles(){
    if (listLayer.size() == 0) {
        return layers;
    } else {
        layers = "&layers=";
        for (String location : listLayer) {
            if (layers.equals("&layers="))
                layers = layers + location;
            else
                layers = layers + "," + location;
        }
        return layers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How many layers do you need to render? Are you required to render all of them at once?

If you can, you'd better to create one WmsTileProvider per Layer; this will give you the ability to granularly enable or disable layers.

If instead you need to (or want) to render all of them at once, you can use your getTileUrl in a smarter way:

Create a method in your WmsTileProvider that enables you to set the layers (you can create a mLayers String variable inside the class and change the getLayersTitles method to change this variable instead of returning it), then call this method whenever you need to change the list of layers and a call clearTileCache:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay#clearTileCache%28%29

Your tiles will be reloaded with the new layers...

Code (sorry for bad formatting):

```
public void setLayerArea(List<String> listLayer){
  this.mLayers = getLayerTitles(listLayer);
}   

private String getLayerTitles(List<String> listLayer){
if (listLayer.size() == 0) {
    return "DEFAULT LAYERS";
} else {
    layers = "&layers=";
    for (String location : listLayer) {
        if (layers.equals("&layers="))
            layers = layers + location;
        else
            layers = layers + "," + location;
    }
    return layers;
}
} 

public WmsTileProvider getOsgeoWmsTileProvider() {

//This is configured for:
// http://beta.sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/maps/services
// (TODO check that this WMS service still exists at the time you try to run this demo,
// if it doesn't, find another one that supports EPSG:900913
final String WMS_FORMAT_STRING =
        "http://202.90.153.87:8080/geoserver/flood_100/wms?" +
                "service=WMS" +
                "&version=1.1.0" +
                "&request=GetMap" +
                "&bbox=%f,%f,%f,%f" +
                "&width=256" +
                "&height=256" +
                "&srs=EPSG:900913" +
                "&format=image/png" +
                "&transparent=true" +
                "&tiled=true";

WmsTileProvider tileProvider = new WmsTileProvider(256,256) {
    @Override
    public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        double[] bbox = getBoundingBox(x, y, zoom);

        String s = String.format(Locale.US, WMS_FORMAT_STRING, bbox[MINX],
                bbox[MINY], bbox[MAXX], bbox[MAXY]);

        s = s + this.mLayers;

        Log.e("MapLayers", s);
        URL url = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        return url;
    }
};

return tileProvider;
}
```